# How can i select only id of min created date in each group

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

Imagine next tables

Ticket Table

```
 ========================
| id | question          |
 ========================
| 1  | Can u help me :)? |
 ========================
```

UserEntry Table

```
 ======================================================
| id | answer               | dateCreated  | ticket_id |
 ======================================================
| 2  | It's my plessure :)? | 2016-08-05   |     1     |     
=======================================================
| 3  | How can i help u ?   | 2016-08-06   |     1     |
 ======================================================
```

So how can I only get id of row for each group which have min date value

**So my expected answer should be like that**

```
 ====
| id |
 ====
| 2  |
 ====
```

**UPDATE:**

I got the solution in next query

> SELECT id FROM UserEntry WHERE datecreated IN (SELECT MIN(datecreated) FROM CCUserEntry GROUP BY ticket_id)

**Improved Answer**

> SELECT id FROM UserEntry WHERE (ticket_id, datecreated) IN
>     (SELECT ticket_id, MIN(datecreated) FROM UserEntry GROUP BY ticket_id);

**Also this is a good and right answer too** (*NOTE*: **DISTINCT ON** is not a part of the SQL standard.)

> SELECT DISTINCT ON (ue.ticket_id) ue.id 
>   FROM UserEntry ue
>   ORDER BY ue.ticket_id, ue.datecreated

Comment: Help us help you - please share the tables' structures, some sample data, and the result you're trying to get for it.

Comment: Good luck with the "works on all database engines" part ;)

Comment: @Andomar i saw your edits but i was already edited what u did, so why i didn't accept your edits, anyway thanks for ur help :)

Comment: @Mureinik i edited my question and added a sample design of tables.

Comment: I don't understand. You `SELECT entry.id , MIN(entry.datecreated)`, but you only want `entry.id`? Then `SELECT entry.id` only. Where is the problem?

Comment: The result you are showing doesn't match the query. With the query shown you don't select only ID 2, you select ID 3, too.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner i am forced to use *MIN(entry.datecreated)* because i need the row in each group with min createdDate and i don't know how i select only id and move this *MIN(entry.datecreated)* out side selection, got me ?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner imagine i have a date which i am grouping it by ticket id, like in example, so ignore the query in question, i will delete it so no one will be confused, so how i select first id of min created date in each group

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems you want to select the ID with the minimum `datecreated`. That is simple: select the minimum date and then select the id(s) matching this date.

```
SELECT id FROM UserEntry WHERE datecreated = (SELECT MIN(datecreated) FROM UserEntry);
```

If you are sure you won't have ties or if you are fine with just one row anyway, you can also use `FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY` which doesn't have a tie clause in PostgreSQL unfortunately.

```
SELECT id FROM UserEntry ORDER BY datecreated FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY;
```

**UPDATE:** You want the entry ID for the minimum date per ticket. Per ticket translates to `GROUP BY ticket_id` in SQL.

```
SELECT ticket_id, id FROM UserEntry WHERE (ticket_id, datecreated) IN
  (SELECT ticket_id, MIN(datecreated) FROM UserEntry GROUP BY ticket_id);
```

The same can be achieved with window functions where you read the table only once:

```
SELECT ticket_id, id
FROM
(
  SELECT ticket_id, id, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ticket_id ORDER BY datecreated) AS rnk
  FROM UserEntry 
) ranked
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

(Change `SELECT ticket_id, id` to `SELECT id` if you want the queries not to show the ticket ID, which would make the results harder to understand of course :-)

Comment: i want to select minimum id in each group, so for example if i have group of 2 i want to select only id of minimum date, got me ?

Comment: You mean the entry ID for the minimum date per ticket?

Comment: yes exactly :) each row id which have min createdDate per tickets

Comment: Okay, I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank u very much, actually your first answer helped me much, and of course your answer after edit is acceptable too, anyway i updated my post before i see your updates, but i will do accept your answer because you helped much and the answer is right too

Comment: Your own solution is incorrect. You select the minimum ID per ticket alright, but then you select any row that happens to match one of the found dates regardless of the ticket.

Comment: i updated my answer with your answer, but i think your answer will have same problem too, i mean my answer above like yours, i see only difference is using * WHERE (ticket_id, datecreated)* >> ticket_id with where condition

Comment: That is the difference. When I find that 2016-08-05 is the minimum date for ticket 1, I select the ID for the ticket 1 record with that date. When you find that 2016-08-05 is the minimum date for ticket 1, you select all IDs for all ticket records that happen to have that date.

Comment: yes you are right, got your point now, i was wrong, Thanks for your help, and it's really good point to understand

Comment: This is all needless complication. Simply use `DISTINCT ON` (see [answer to dupe question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7630564/939860)) - or other query techniques to [optimize performance in certain situations](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25536748/939860).

Answer (score 6):

You may want `fetch first row only` or `distinct on` (if you care about more than one ticket):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (ue.ticket_id) ue.id 
FROM UserEntry ue
ORDER BY ue.ticket_id, ue.date_created
```

This will get the `id` on the row with the minimum `date_created` value.

Comment: the query must use **GROUP BY** because i want id of row which have *MIN(datecreated)* for each group (I want to group by ticket) per ticket

Comment: @mibrahim.iti: The query looks correct to me. Have you even tried it? Do you know what PostgreSQL's `DISTINCT ON` does?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner yes but didn't work with me, i see also it's correct but it doesn't work, anyway it's just DISTINCT for postgres

Comment: @ThorstenKettner yes the query is incorrect, it's fire *ORDER BY ue.ticket_id, ue.datecreated* actually it needs *ue.datecreated* to be in selection too, i added it to query and tested but it return wrong answer too, it return all entries not just min

Comment: The final query tested by me is **SELECT DISTINCT (ue.ticket_id), ue.id , ue.datecreated
FROM UserEntry ue
where ticket_id = 86523
ORDER BY ue.ticket_id, ue.datecreated** and that ticket id have two rows so i was expecting only one anyway even it have more than two rows, but i got two rows which means the query is wrong

Comment: @mibrahim.iti . . . No, the query uses `DISTINCT ON`.  That is very, very different from `SELECT DISTINCT`.  If I had intended the latter, I would have written it.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes, you are right, Your query is different and there are difference between DISTINCT and DISTINCT ON, Thanks for your helpful answer :)

Comment: @mibrahim.iti . . . This is usually the simplest and best performing way to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: To add clarity to this answer: everything works like a charm:

1. It sorts the table on _id (treat is as group by _id)  

2. Inside the "groups" sorts it by creation date (treat is as min(created_at)  
 
3. Then distinct on takes the first entry for  id => it always takes the row with min(created_at)

Answer (score 0):

A solution with ANSI SQL that works on a wide range of DBMS that support [modern SQL](http://modern-sql.com/) is to use window functions:

```
select id
from (
   select id, row_number() over (partition by ticket_id order by date_created) as rn
   from userentry
) t
where rn = 1;
```

Note that in Postgres, Gordon's solution using `distinct on ()` is usually faster then using window functions